# Allow moderators to delete orphaned tag-wikis

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, orphaned-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Homeless orphan tag wikis need original names, euthanised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108631/homeless-orphan-tag-wikis-need-original-names-euthanised)

As most of the orphaned wikis are caused by merged tags, it would make sense to allow the moderators to delete them, as they are not associated with any tag. Alternatively, it would be fine if the moderators could associate the tag wiki to an existing tag.