# Please complete the orphan wiki lifecycle

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderator-tools, tag-wiki, orphaned-wiki

It was recently announced that tags with exactly one tag that also possess a complete tag wiki [will not be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki). This is [welcome news](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149385/132073) for many smaller sites.

On Board and Card games, we have [significant content in orphaned wikis](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/admin/orphan-wikis) which we would like to reinstate. There is [substantial community interest](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/942/lets-save-our-tags) in performing this work. However this is hampered by several factors:

- Only high rep users can see orphaned wikis.
- Orphan wikis have no indication (other than their content) of which tag they were originally associated with.
- Orphan wikis cannot be restored or relinked to a new tag through the interface - the text must be physically cut and pasted into a completely new wiki, which is tedious and also loses all history in the process.
- Orphan wikis cannot be deleted, by moderators or anyone else, so the list is hard to navigate, and cannot be managed.
- Editing and saving an orphan wiki appears to hang the interface (not that it's very useful - it's still a mostly invisible orphan).

Most of these points are mentioned [in this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108631/homeless-orphan-tag-wikis-need-original-names-euthanised), but I am re-raising this as a single issue because of its timeliness. At present, orphan wiki functionality is only half-implemented. It seems like with just a little more work, we could have a significantly more useful process here. If we could raise the restriction on orphans, and [allow moderators to delete orphans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90752/allow-moderators-to-delete-orphaned-tag-wikis), we would have most of what we need. Relinking would be nice, but is not essential.

As it is, we are seriously contemplating pasting all the orphaned content into some public location, simply to allow the B&CG community to *improve their own site*! Surely there's a better way?

Comment: I was told back when the tag killer became non-systematic that the name of the tag is hard-deleted and cannot be recovered. Surprising for a system that otherwise never hard-deletes.

Comment: @Gilles: Somebody _really dislikes_ singleton tags. ;-)