# If a tag is removed and later created again, is the original tag-info recreated, too?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

When a tag is created, the tag-info is available at `https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/[tagname]/info`. (Or this url shows that it is currently empty.) After the tag is removed, then the above address no longer shows the original tag-info.

Recently in another discussion an experienced user [mentioned in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242090/is-it-possible-to-find-tag-info-tag-wiki-and-tag-excerpt-for-the-tag-which-was/242091#comment973088_242091) that if a tag with the same name is created again, then also the tag-info is recreated:

> I will not test this but IIRC if you recreate the tag, the previous tag-wiki gets re-instantiated. I remember I had seen such report but don't know if that was a fluke, a one-time incident or by-design.

However this contradicts my experience with a removed and recreated tag on one of the sites. (I will include details below.) This was in 2012, so it is possible that the behavior of removed tag-wikis changed since then.

**TL;DR:** So I am basically asking for some "official" info on this: If a tag with the same name as a previously removed tag is created again, does it automatically has the original tag-info?

---

On instance of this I remember is (algebra) tag on math.SE. This tag is 
[currently blacklisted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/should-the-algebra-tag-be-blacklisted). However, before the blacklisting it was removed and created again.

At some point, the tag-wiki looked like this (as mentioned in [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3481#3481)):

> DEPRECATED TAG! Please DO NOT use this. (algebra-precalculus) or (abstract-algebra) might be more appropriate tags. See tag wiki for details.

However, I was able to find a [message in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2012/8/28) mentioning a new tag-excerpt after the tag was created again. You can see in the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/187329/revisions) that the original tag-info was lost. The fact that the old tag-info was removed after the deletion was also mentioned [in this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3481#comment13798_3481).

Comment: I just [burninated a tag with tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash-2017), we can try adding it tomorrow to sandbox to test this once and for all. :)

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure, but mods can see orphaned wikis (wikis from now-deleted tags) and I see a bunch of duplicate orphan wikis (for tags that keep being recreated), which implies the wikis needed to be recreated every time. This does mean if you *want* to recreate the wiki you can at least ask a mod to find the old one

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Cai. Maybe you'd like to repost (and perhaps expand) your comment (the part mentioning that the orhaned tag-wikis are accessible to mods) as an answer to this related question: [Is it possible to find tag-info (tag-wiki and tag-excerpt) for the tag which was deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242090) (I'll wait a bit - at least until the end of bounty period - but if no simple way for non-diamond users is suggested there, I might as well accept the answer suggesting to ask a moderator.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If a tag with the same name as a previously removed tag is created again, does it automatically has the original tag-info?

**No.**

---

I have performed a full scale test to prove this, by following those steps:

- Found a tag that should not exist, but had wiki text. ([winterbash-2017](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2017))
- Burninated the tag by removing it from all questions which had it.
- Waited for a while to let the system delete it.
- Created the tag again by adding it to the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions).
- Waited for over a full day.

No tag wiki was there.